# SQL Server 2012 : Create Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule 
(
     Section DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY(CourseID, Section, EmployeeID),
     CourseID VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES Course(CourseID) NOT NULL,
     EmployeeID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
     StartTime TIME NULL,
     Days DATE NULL,
     Length TIME NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Enrollment 
(
     StudentID INT Primary key (StudentID, CourseID, Section) NOT NULL,
     CourseID VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES Course(CourseID) NOT NULL,
     Section DATETIME NOT NULL REFERENCES Schedule(Section)
)
```

2nd table did not get created, where did I go wrong?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What are the exact error messages you got? You've dumped a mess of unformatted SQL with no relevant information and said "it didn't work*.

Comment: What database?  What is the error??

Comment: It is SQL Server 2012 and The Error is 'There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Schedule' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Enrollmen__Secti__52593CB8'.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you made the primary key in the Schedule table a natural/combined key.

Try creating a stand alone column for this purpose instead. I've included an example below that shows the differences.

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.PK_TEST (
                       Col_A INT NOT NULL
                      ,Col_B INT NOT NULL
                      ,Primary Key(Col_A,Col_B)
                      )


Create table DBO.PK_TEST_2 (
                            Col_A int NOT NULL
                           ,Col_B int NOT NULL
                           ,Col_C as (cast(Col_A as nvarchar) 
                           + cast(Col_B as nvarchar)) PERSISTED NOT NULL
                           ,primary key(Col_C)
                           )
```

[image]